# Keep Indentation on Echoed HTML

Tags: phpstorm

I am getting into PHPStorm and really like the option to reformat code. I have mine setup just the way I like with one exception. I often echo HTML in this fashion.

```
echo '<section'>;
    echo '<h2>Some Heading</h2>;
    echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
echo '</section>';
```

When I reformat code this cleans the above code into this

```
echo '<section'>;
echo '<h2>Some Heading</h2>;
echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
echo '</section>';
```

Is it possible to keep the format above for any echoed html in PHPSstorm? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use HEREDOC here?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which makes the code clearer and should not be reformatted:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOF
<section>
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</section>
EOF;
?>
```

Comment: If you use `HTML` as a marker instead of `EOF` then PhpStorm will inject HTML language into that fragment (if you need such functionality, of course)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is really powerful in this regard, why don't you just do the following:

```
<?php /* do something */ ?>
<section>
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</section>
<?php /* do more things */ ?>
```

you don't even need to echo the HTML. In the HTML component, you even have access to scoped variables used in the preceding lines/files (if, for example, the file containing this HTML was `include`d)

If you want to capture the output to use later, or display later, then use `ob_start()` to start output buffering and `$output = ob_get_clean();` to release the buffer and capture the output.

Or, if, for example, the code is in a controller file, you can "include" files (it works really well in tandem with the Output Buffering method I described above), and roll your own version of templating.

Something like:

`some_layout.php`

```
<?php /* do something */ ?>
<section>
    <h2>Some Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem <?=$wow?> dolor sit amet...</p>
</section>
<?php /* do more things */ ?>
```

`controller.php`

```
public function showSomeLayout() {
    $wow = 2;

    ob_start();
    include 'some_layout.php';
    return new SomeResponseObject(ob_get_clean()); // or just print here
}
```

A really neat trick is that you can actually `include` any type of file. For example, if you want to inject your app version into a javascript script node in the DOM, you can do the following:

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>var appVersion = <?=$v?>;</script>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

including `index.html`, with `$v` available in the current scope, will result in $v being injected into the page, and available to javascript.

(That's actually a pretty shitty example, but you can do it with `.js` files, as well, if you're capturing all requests/piping them through your app, and serving files yourself.